# Passing a varying parameter to a method

Tags: php, mysql

I use the below method to get messages(I don't use SELECT * just wrote it like that for the question). Sometimes I need only 10 messages, and sometimes I need all the messages. What is the best way to accomplish something like that?

```
public function receivedMessages($user_id) {
    if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * 
                                        FROM messages 
                                        WHERE receiver_id = ? 
                                        LIMIT 10"))
    {
        $q->bind_param("i", $user_id);

        $q->execute();

        $rows = $this->helperClass->bindResults($q);
        $q->close();

        return $rows;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a parameter in the method: `receivedMessages($user_id,$limit = false)`. If `false` select all, if a number, use the limit.

Comment: `public function receivedMessages($user_id,$limit)` ??

Comment: Ok ... I knew it was something like that ... but how do I write out the query? Do I just check if `$limit` is false and do a huge if else? That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another `variable` -

```
public function receivedMessages($user_id, $limit = false) {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = ?";
    if(!empty($limit)) {
        $qry .= " LIMIT $limit"; // If limit passed then add limit statement to query
    }
    if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare($qry))
    {
        $q->bind_param("i", $user_id);

        $q->execute();

        $rows = $this->helperClass->bindResults($q);
        $q->close();

        return $rows;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that `$limit` be `LIMIT ?` and then `$q->bind_param("i", $user_id, $limit)` ?

Comment: If you are passing the `$limit` internally then no need of that.

Comment: Aha ... so if the limit is not from a user then it's fine.

Comment: Yup.. Else the `if` prepare it accordingly. :)

Comment: Ok. I set that limit number. So it should be fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function receivedMessages($user_id,$num_0f_messages) {

if($num_of_messages === 0)){

//select all
} else {

if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * 
                                    FROM messages 
                                    WHERE receiver_id = ? 
                                    LIMIT ?"))
{
    $q->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $num_of_messages);

    $q->execute();

    $rows = $this->helperClass->bindResults($q);
    $q->close();

    return $rows;
}
    return false;
} 
}
```

to get all the messages,you do `receivedMessages(1,0) ;` 
to limit the messages,say only 5 result set, `receivedMessages(1,8)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution according to the comments

```
public function receivedMessages($user_id,$limit=0) {

if($limit==0){
   $sql="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = ?";
} else {
   $sql="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = ? LIMIT $limit";
}

if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare($sql))
    {
        $q->bind_param("i", $user_id);

        $q->execute();

        $rows = $this->helperClass->bindResults($q);
        $q->close();

        return $rows;
    }
        return false;
}
```